# Unable to handle download file in Chrome using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In the AUT when user clicks on the Excel button then a file should be downloaded.
In the past in other web applications I have handled it using the chrome options as:
But in my current application I see that when user clicks on Excel button then a new tab is open which presents the file explorer pop up. The question here is how to handle this. Even if I switch window handles still I will have the pop up which I don't want. How can I handle this situation.

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", download_dir);
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the (python) code that I've used in the past to download files

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
"safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

(obviously this is in python, I can take a stab at making a version for Java or you can try if you like)

Answer (score 0):

I developed a [library](https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/selenium-download-kpi) which is dealing more clearly in such case. You can generate a ChromeOptions object with given download folder and use a one line method call to download a file and verify succession:

```
private SeleniumDownloadKPI seleniumDownloadKPI;

@BeforeEach
void setUpTest() {
    seleniumDownloadKPI =
         new SeleniumDownloadKPI("/tmp/downloads");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions =
            seleniumDownloadKPI.generateDownloadFolderCapability();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}

@Test
void downloadAttachTest() throws InterruptedException {
    adamInternetPage.navigateToPage(driver);
    seleniumDownloadKPI.fileDownloadKPI(
            adamInternetPage.getFileDownloadLink(), "SpeedTest_16MB.dat");
    waitBeforeClosingBrowser();
}
```